# Better way to do achieve a billing table?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to make a billing table. It has columns Cust_ID (Unique Field), Zone, Mode, Weight, Amount. I have different Excel workbooks with rates and zones for each customer. The amount depends on the Zone, weight & zone.

Now, say I have ten customers, who have ten zones individually, for each of ten modes and ten weight slabs. I am get amount from:

```
=INDIRECT("'[Customer_Rate_2015.xlsx]"&A2&"'!"&O2)
```

A2 - Customer ID, O2 - cells in the billing table which refers to the weight zone according to the mode and returns the cell address

For selecting O2:

```
=IF(F2="air",IF(E2=0.1,CONCATENATE(LEFT(RIGHT(CELL("address",'[Customer_Rate_2015.xlsx]1001'!$E$3),3),1),RIGHT(CELL("address",'[Customer_Rate_2015.xlsx]1001'!$E$3),1)),""))
```

Now, for each mode and zone and weight separate rates are there
for which I have to every time get the value of each cell through the above formula.

Is there a better or alternative way so the value of `O2` in the indirect formula can be selected, so I don't have to write those 100+ IF statements?

Answer (score 0):

Use a database for your data and then create a query with Zone, Weight, and Mode parameters to get the rate to calculate the amount. If you don't know how to use a database, learn, its not hard and its the best gift you could ever give yourself, and you can kiss monstrous nested if statements goodbye..(almost :)

You *can* also use VBA to query your Excel sheet with your rates.

A function to do this would look something like this (requires reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects**)

```
Function GetRate(Weight, Zone, Mode)
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    SqlState = "Select Rate FROM [MyRatesSheet$] WHERE [Zone]=" & Zone & _
              " AND [Weight]=" & Weight & _
              " AND [Mode]='" & Mode & "'"

    rs.Open SqlState, con, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    If Not rs.EOF Then GetRate = rs(0)

    GoTo cleanup
errorhandler:
    GetRate = Err.Description
cleanup:
    If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    If con.State = adStateOpen Then con.Close
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then Set rs = Nothing
    If Not con Is Nothing Then Set con = Nothing
End Function
```

Which you would reference in your worksheet with

```
=GetRate(H18,I18,J18)
```